# Not getting UserDefaults for some keys

Tags: ios, swift

I am pretty new to iOS development and can't find out about this one. I created Root.plist and added some boolean preferences. Some of them I can get using `UserDefaults.standard.bool`, but some of them I get always false.

Ex. this call works:

```
UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "zpevnik_hide_identical_chord_sequences")
```

This call doesn't (always returns false):

```
UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "zpevnik_zobrazit_akordy")
```

Edited that file mostly manually cause I found it easier than using xcode UI, so maybe there's something wrong in that file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>StringsTable</key>
    <string>Root</string>
    <key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSToggleSwitchSpecifier</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>pref_title_zobrazit_akordy</string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>zpevnik_zobrazit_akordy</string>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSToggleSwitchSpecifier</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>pref_title_zobrazit_komentare</string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>zpevnik_zobrazit_komentare</string>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSToggleSwitchSpecifier</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>pref_title_zobrazit_text</string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>zpevnik_zobrazit_text</string>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSToggleSwitchSpecifier</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>pref_title_multiple_columns</string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>zpevnik_multiple_columns</string>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSToggleSwitchSpecifier</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>pref_title_hide_identical_chord_sequences</string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>zpevnik_hide_identical_chord_sequences</string>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>

    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: I've copied and pasted your code and the syntax of your xml is correct, and the code for retrieving the values is correct. It works for me, the correct values are retrieved from the settings.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. Any idea where else could be the problem?

Comment: You should post the code in context and include the steps you take which leads to the error

Comment: But what other code to post? I don't see anything else relevant to this.

Answer (score 0):

in your AppDelegate - you can test for the existence of keys - and if this fails - set them.

```
extension UserDefaults {
    
    func valueExists(forKey key: String) -> Bool {
        return object(forKey: key) != nil
    }
    
}

if !UserDefaults.standard.valueExists(forKey: "zpevnik_zobrazit_akordy){
    print("⚠️ warning setting defaults")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "zpevnik_zobrazit_akordy")
}
```